# Is there a way to make a high order function not allocate a new item in memory in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, memory-management

Take these functions

```
fun main() {
    val variable = "2"
    val variable2 = "2"
    println(System.identityHashCode(variable))
    println(System.identityHashCode(variable2))
    test2 { 
        "Test $variable"
    }
    println(System.identityHashCode(variable))
    println(System.identityHashCode(variable2))
 }

fun test2(block: () -> String) {
    println(System.identityHashCode(block()))
    println(block())
}
```

The output is

```
748432199
748432199
930990596  < -- This is the issue, I want it to be 748432199
Test 2
748432199
748432199
```

The numbers (748.., 930) should be memory locations of the strings. I duplicated the first two to demonstrate the Java string pool and that that the two variables there are pointing to the same point in memory.

It appears that with this lambda, it is allocating a new string when it makes it into the `test2` block. In my application, I am using this for logging. It seems like it is fairly expensive to do in an app which logs frequently. I saw a fair bit of memory allocations (more than I'd expect) while logging. I understand *why* this is happening after reading some documentation, but I am not quite sure on how to best address this, other than just converting my functions to pass in string directly and get rid of the high order functions.

Is there a nice way to resolve this? Or is this not possible, and I need to use a normal function, like so:

```
fun test3(message: String) {
    println(message)
}
```

Comment: "It seems like..." - are you actually monitoring the memory use of the application and are seeing problems?

Comment: Yes sorry, my wording is off. I am profiling the application and was noticing more memory allocations than i would expect. GC frees them in time, so I am not running OOM, but it would still be good to solve this in case it ever became an issue. The application logs a fair amount, so it would be a sizable saving to resolve this.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `System.identityHashCode()`, but it looks like are you expecting different strings, `"2"` and `"Test 2"`, to have the same hash code?

Comment: I don't understand your question given the example code. Why should `"Test $variable"`, which resolves to `"Test 2"`, be the same object as `"2"`? Those two strings aren't even equal to each other (i.e., they can never be the same object).

Comment: "The numbers (748.., 930) should be memory locations of the strings." No, they can be but they don't have to be (and I don't think they still are on modern JVMs). This doesn't really matter for the rest of the question of course.